# Bug with negative amounts in PayPal API

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to use a negative amount with the **PayPal Adaptive Payments API**. To start with, this seems to work:

```
    'item' => [
      {
        'itemPrice' => '25.00',
        'name' => 'Cryptex - 16Gb USB Drive',
        'price' => '25',
        'itemCount' => 1
      },
      {
        'quantity' => 1,
        'name' => 'Special Discount',
        'price' => '-2.50'
      },
      {
        'itemPrice' => '5.00',
        'name' => 'Shipping',
        'price' => '5.00',
        'itemCount' => 1
      }
    ]
```

Here is an example of what I see after submitting this as JSON, and updating the items:

[image]

As you can see, the price **IS** correct ... yet there is no sign of the discounted amount? Its obviously taking it into account - otherwise the price would have been £30, not £27.50 (which is after the £2.50 discount)

What gives? Is this a bug in PayPals system?

FWIW, the emails are also broken - they don't show the discount amount at all.

**UPDATE:** I've opened a ticket with PayPal tech support, as I'm pretty sure this is a bug with their system, and not something that can be fixed this end :( Damn annoying!

**UPDATE 2:** Reply from PayPal:

> PayPal Adaptive Payments do not support negative item values. Since you did not pass the  <itemPrice> in your API Call, the system did not throw the following error message:
>
> ```
> [errorId] => 580022
> [domain] => PLATFORM
> [subdomain] => Application
> [severity] => Error
> [category] => Application
> [message] => Invalid request parameter: itemPrice cannot be negative
> ```
>
> I can see that the following was submitted to PayPal:
>
> ```
> <item>
> <name>Special Discount</name>
> <identifier></identifier>
> <price>-2.50</price>
> <itemPrice></itemPrice>
> <itemCount></itemCount>
> <any>[quantity: null]</any>
> </item>
> ```
>
> This object is basically incomplete and in order to apply discounts, you should apply them > onto the price for the main item and then submit it to PayPal.

I'm really not sure what they're suggestion I do? An example cart, would be:

```
Item 1 -  £10 
Item 2 -  £20 
Item 3 -  £50 
Item 4 -  £10 
Delivery - £5
Total   -  £95
```

As an encouragement, we sometimes will offer coupons... so it could be "£10 off orders over £50". So in the above case above, it would drop the overall price to £85.

I'm really not sure  what they are suggesting as an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. Normal payments don't have that restriction (I pass a negative amount item just like what you describe on a frequent basis).

What they're telling you to do is take the discount off another item. So your example cart with that discount would be

```
Item 1 -  £10 
Item 2 -  £20 
Item 3 -  £40 <-- Removed £10 discount
Item 4 -  £10 
Delivery - £5
Total   -  £85 <-- total reflects this
```

Comment: Yeah - its a bit rubbish really. The problem with doing that, is that its gonna confuse the hell out of people. Some coupons can be for "all" items.. whereas others may be limited to a specific product. After talking with their techs, I think the only option I have - is to not even both passing a breakdown. i.e just have the grand total - and thats it. Then (as we do already) have it broken down in the invoice email we send out ourselves, and also the buyer/seller panels, where they can view transactions. Still stupid to me :(

Comment: Yeah, I have some scenarios where it just doesn't make sense to pass the breakdown. Really that only affects your PayPal users since credit card customers can't see that data anyways.

Comment: @Macavity - ya... still amazes me they don't offer a discount option. According to the paypal tech, "there wasn't enough demand for it" ... which I find hard to believe!